# Graphql Schema (Apollo) nested object

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have an API endpoint that returns the following data:

```
{
  "2017": {
      "May": [
           {},
           {}
       ],
       "June": []
   },
   "2018": {}
  }
```

How can I create a schema for those nested objects as it seems I cannot create nested objects in the schema.

I am using the `typeDefinitions` with `graphql-tools` which works well for objects and arrays of objects but I could not find a way to tackle this.

a typical type looks like:

```
type Venue { 
  name: String, 
  url: String, 
  streetAddress: String, 
  streetAddress2: String, 
  streetAddress3: String, 
  city: String, 
  postalCode: String, 
  country: String, 
  phoneNumber: String, 
  info: String 
}
```

and can be used in another type as follow:

```
type Event {
    title: String,
    subTitle: String,
    slug: String,
    venues: [Venue],
    ...
}
```

but I cannot do something like:

```
type Calendar {
    year: {
        month: [Event]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to separate the nested objects:

```
type Year {
    month: [Event]
}    

type Calendar {
    year: Year
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is that there is no key "year" it is "2017" or "2018"

Comment: So maybe `fragments` would be good for you? see https://learngraphql.com/basics/fragments

Comment: Or maybe `GraphQLScalar` for the `Calendar` type, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34229603/3883957

Comment: In any case, you might want to change your model to a model with the year in its own field alongside the `Year` type, or even as a field inside the `Year` type itself, and then `Calendar` contains `years: [Year]`